# Calculate $\mathbb E(5 - 3X) - D(2 - X)$ with $Uniform$ ~ $[-3, 3]$

Tags: expected-value, variance

I have continuous uniform distribution $Uniform$ ~ $[-3, 3]$. And I want to calculate $\mathbb E(5 - 3X) - D(2 - X)$. But I am getting conflicting results:

**First solution**
$$\mathbb E(5 - 3X) - D(2 - X) = \mathbb E(5 - 3X) - \mathbb E((2-X)^2) + \mathbb E^2(2-X) = \mathbb E(5) - \mathbb E(3X) - [\mathbb E(4) - \mathbb E(4X) + \mathbb E(X^2)] + [\mathbb E(2) - \mathbb E(X)]^2 = 5 - 3\mathbb E(X) - 4 + 4\mathbb E(X) - \mathbb E(X^2) + 4 - 4\mathbb E(X) + \mathbb E^2(X) = 5 + \mathbb E(X) = 5$$

**Second solution**
$$\mathbb E(5 - 3X) - D(2 - X) = \mathbb E(5) - \mathbb E(3X) - D(X) = 5 - 3 \cdot0 - 3 = 2$$

I used the linearity of the expectation and the fact that $\mathbb E(X) = \frac{-3 + 3}{2} = 0$.

I can't understand what the error is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second calculation is correct.  The first is incorrect.  It should be instead
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[5-3X] - \operatorname{Var}[2-X]
&= \operatorname{E}[5 - 3X] - \operatorname{E}[(2-X)^2] + \operatorname{E}^2[2-X] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[5] - \operatorname{E}[3X] - \operatorname{E}[4 - 4X + X^2] + (\operatorname{E}[2] - \operatorname{E}[X])^2 \\
&= 5 - 3 \operatorname{E}[X] - 4 + 4\operatorname{E}[X] - \operatorname{E}[X^2] + (2 - 0)^2 \\
&= 5 - 4 - \operatorname{E}[X^2] + 4 \\
&= 5 - \operatorname{E}[X^2].
\end{align}$$

But what is $\operatorname{E}[X^2]$?  It is certainly not $0$.  It is $$\operatorname{E}[X^2] = \int_{x=-3}^3 x^2 \cdot \frac{1}{6} \, dx = \left[\frac{x^3}{18}\right]_{x=-3}^3 = \frac{2(27)}{18} = 3.$$  Thus the result is $5 - 3 = 2$, same as with the second method.

Comment: Is using $D$ for variance a common notation? I can't say I've ever come across it.

Comment: @user170231 It took me a minute to figure out what it meant, so it certainly wasn't familiar to me.  Not sure what it stands for.  "Dispersion?"  "Divergence?"  Most people use "Var" or "V."